# make sure `response.getOutputStream().write()` was received

Tags: java, http, networking, tcp

I write a response to an HTTP request in the following manner:
`response.getOutputStream().write()`

I want to make sure the client received it.

It must be possible, as TCP sends acknowledgements.

This requirement also implies that the write MUST be a blocking operation (it's fine by me!).

So how do I know if it's done the above way (I suspect it's not)? Any specification that guarantees it? **Any way to make that happen?** I'm with Tomcat 6.

... PS, I mean any way *besides* making the client send this acknowledgement in another HTTP request :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you can make sure you flush the output stream buffer:

```
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

It guarantees that the data is actually sent out. TCP will make sure that it arrives or else will give your server an error which will translate into an IOException.

So in short, if you can write and not get an error, your client did receive the data. At least on the TCP stack. The client is obviously responsible for consuming the message.

TCP provides both data integrity and delivery guarantee. It will keep retransmitting until the receiver acknowledges the reception of the packet. But all this happens inside the TCP stack. Your code can just assume it happened or you received an error. Only these two cases are possible.

Also, you might want to make sure you close the output stream or else your client might be sitting there buffering data until it receives an end of stream.

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

TCP only knows that the data has been received by the peer. It doesn't know that the peer *application* has received the data. And TCP writes are asynchronous, so the error could be detected long after the write or flush has returned to the sending application.

The application could acknowledge receipt via another HTTP transaction but HTTP is supposed to be stateless and doing so would violate that rule.

I suggest you look up the 'two-army problem'.

What you should do instead is make your transactions *idempotent* (look it up) Then it is the client's responsibility to ensure the transaction occurs. If the client does not get the response he should merely repeat the transaction. Put a low limit on the number of retries, say two or three.

Comment: +1 great answer! However you conflict yourself by saying `HTTP is supposed to be stateless` and `not get the response he should merely repeat the transaction`, because, how would I get a response (I *assume* you meant "server" and not "client") without making another HTTP request..

Comment: Besides, who said "HTTP is **supposed to**..".. There are "sessions" etc' to make it stateful anyway... just as a side not.

Comment: So basically you suggest, in order to make this messenging system (that's exactly what it is) idempotent I better move the handling of that to the client side while making it also confirm receiving of a message explicitly, correct?

Comment: @Poni (1) You would get another response by issuing another request. (2) It is the HTTP RFCs that define it as a stateless protocol. (3) if the transaction is idempotent there is no need to confirm the arrival of a response.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Let's leave the "debate" of HTTP's stateness to otheres. (2) `two-army problem` and `idempotent` are nice definitions to what I already know yet I'm uncertain how to implement it. From what you're saying I understand now that you meant to make the transactions *on the server side* idempotent. Well, that brings me to the same point I was when posted this question - and actually I already have the transaction idempotent - it's the client side that makes the problem I guess. Well, I've written a lot, if it confuses please refer to the original question, or ask. Thanks again!

Comment: @Poni A transaction is a transaction. It is either idempotent or not. The way to make it so is to give it a unique sequence number, and when retrying at the client, reuse the same number: at the server, if you've seen the number before, send the same response as before. The responsibility for getting the transaction through is the client's, not the server's. If the client doesn't get the response, he will retry. Problem solved.

Comment: @Poni, thats the point you are missing here. The only way you can get the client to ack is to get the client to send a "ok" back to the server. Or you can create a background thread that waits for responses in some kind of order, and respond to failures "without waiting".

Comment: @Siddharth Note that I'm eliminating the whole problem. If the transaction is idempotent, you can make it the client's responsibility to retry it until it gets a response, and eliminate the problem of the ACKed response altogether. The server doesn't have the responsibility of ensuring the client got the response, the client does.

Comment: Well, in that case @Poli needs to change his thought process on the design itself. He has 2 options, client responsibility or server expecting a ack from client.

Comment: @Siddharth That is exactly what my entire answer is about.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that is what you want ? Test if a write succeeded ? TCP is designed to ensure that it works, if a packet fails you will start getting disconnections and IOExeceptions. Infact you will get RunTimeException. The way to do this will be to send a response back to the source. And wait until the response comes.

When you wait, ensure that you wait for a certain period of time and give up, so that you dont hang.

Assuming you only want to debug your code. If you are wanting to debug use packet sniffers like ethereal. Trust me, once you get your logic right, you wont need the ack packet.

Comment: If a packet fails you may have closed the connection long before TCP detects it, and you certainly will not get a `RuntimeException`. Downvote.

Comment: To start with its a weird question. TCP delivers packets better than UDP. The only way to know if its received ok is to send a ack back. TCP itself sends ACK's, so there is actually no need. On rare occasions the TCP connection goes bad it will throw a RunTimeException.

Comment: @Siddarth All that is correct but you are overlooking that TCP writes are asynchronous. The write doesn't wait until the ACK comes back: it just buffers the data into the socket send buffer in the kernel. So it won't have any reason to throw the IOException as you stated in your answer unless the error condition was already sitting there from a previous I/O, which would take some seconds to occur. So you can't just rely on the absence of IOExceptions from writes as meaning the write has been acknowledged. It hasn't. And the RuntimeException you mentioned is a figment of your imagination.

Comment: The point I was trying to make was, testing a write is a non requirement. Why would a established protocol (like TCP) provide a option to be synchronous. Async is what it does best (as you correctly pointed out). Java abstracts all socket issues in 2 exceptions IOException and RunTimeException.

Comment: And I would like to explain my "figment of imagination". A RunTimeException is thrown when a client closes connection/exits. If you are writing a server that needs to serve multiple clients, you need to catch this, and treat it as "clientClosedConnection" and continue to service other clients. A java server always catch's this exception, even though the ioObjectStream write call does not throw this kind of exception. Kindly note, I wont take the liberty of assaulting you, just because we disagree.

Comment: The point you *actually made* was that a RuntimeException is thrown, when a broken connection is encountered, and you continue to be wrong about that. An IOException is thrown, not a RuntimeException. If you wish to continue disagreeing, please provide a reference from the Javadoc, or the Java Networking Guide that comes with the Javadoc, or the Java Tutorial, that says so, or a pointer to the relevant source code. And Java 'abstracts all socket issues' into a large family of exceptions rooted at IOException but including SocketException, ConnectException, etc